# Existence of a solution for the Laplace equation with sub-linear non-linearity

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

At first, I do apologize if my question is silly. I know that by variational methods it is possible to prove the existence of a solution for
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = u^p & \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \\
u=0 & \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
for $ 1 < p < \frac{n+2}{n-2}$.

But I don't have any idea about the sublinear case, namely, $ p<1$. Also, I don't have any information about the case $p<0$, too.

Comment: for $ 0<p<1$ consider the energy that one would normally use to apply the Mountain Pass Theorem to obtain a solution when $p>1$ (so i mean not the contrained minimization approach).  You can just minimize this energy to obtain a nonzero solution (when $p>1$ this minimization would give you $- \infty$)

Comment: for $p<0$ you might want to look at some papers or books by Marius Ghergu (i believe he has done a bunch of this stuff)